# Custom SharePoint 2013 Lists/Forms in content editor modal pop up only opens in list the form lives in... Not in pop up

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm having issues getting my forms to open in modal pop up after applying code to the content editor web part... The code I'm using is below:

http://sitename/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={A42810A0-786D-4028-B5C8-4B8BAE083CDA}&RootFolder="); 
javascript:return false;" 
target="_self"> 
Global Navigation Request

Please note that I am extremely new to javascript or any coding for that matter. This code has worked well for me in the past (in SharePoint 2010), but now the form won't open in pop up... It only opens up inside the list it lives in and we can't have that... Our users don't need to see any other entries that have been submitted to that specific list...

Is there anything I can do to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems incomplete, but I will assume it's part of an anchor (`<a>` tag), right? That by itself will not open a modal popup.

If you are opening a form's view or edit items from the built-in webparts, whether or not they open in a modal popup depends on a setting of the list. Go to the list's settings, then *Advanced*, and finally set `Launch forms in a dialog?` to `Yes`.

If you want to force modal popups on anything that is not built-in, you have to code, but it's pretty simple. You have to use a global function of SharePoint, `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog`. Usage goes like this:

```
function openModal(pageToOpen) {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
        url: pageToOpen,
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });
}
```

And in any html element:

```
<foo onclick="openModal('http://sitename/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={A42810A0-786D-4028-B5C8-4B8BAE083CDA}&RootFolder=')">
```

If it's an anchor, you still have to keep it from navigating away from the page. A simple `return false` may not work on all browsers, so I suggest you also make a search here in Stack Overflow about that.

Back to `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` - you pass to that function a single parameter, a simple object with some properties. The properties I passed above are:

- **url:** the page that should be opened in the modal popup;
- **width and height**: arbitrary values, really. You don't have to pass these unless you want an arbitrary size for the popup.

More on this method may be found [in the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx). You can see that the parameter object may have more properties than the ones in my example. This documentation is for SharePoint 2010, but this function did not change between SP2010 and SP2013. Good luck and happy coding :)